# Why my model can't see spatie permissions trait method on relationship subquery?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-6, laravel-permission

I use [spatie/laravel-permissions](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) composer package in my laravel projects. 
When I run this query:

```
$jobs = Job::whereIn('id', $ids)->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
    $query->hasRole('company');
})->get();
```

Return error message

> Call to undefined method
>   **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::hasRole()**

How I can fix my problem in my case?

Comment: You're passing a query builder instance instead of a record, `dd($user)` before the query to see

Comment: Post the code where you declared $user

Comment: Here var `$user` is not declared variable. It's `Builder` object

Comment: What you think, how I must rewrite my code to get jobs which users has company role?

Comment: Post the Builder object code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`hasRole`-method](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/b6d7a0f06bacf2cbdc670085a60dd50e160a9cbb/src/Traits/HasRoles.php#L172-L208) is not a scope and can't be used on a Builder instance.

I think you should be able to use the [`role`-scope](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/blob/b6d7a0f06bacf2cbdc670085a60dd50e160a9cbb/src/Traits/HasRoles.php#L51-L88) in your application.

```php
$jobs = Job::whereIn('id', $ids)->whereHas('user', function ($q) {
    return $q->role('company');
})->get();
```